# Instantiate a PHP stdClass in my namespace – fatal error

Tags: php, namespaces

I want to write a small add on for an existing CMS. To do so, I need to extend a class from that CMS' code.

My code will be written inside its own namespace, while the CMS' code does not use namespacing, which basically means it exists inside the global namespace.

Inside my code, I create a new `stdClass`:

`$var = new stdClass();`

With that code is place, it always produces a fatal error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'MyNamespace\something\StdClass' not found in /some/rather/long/path/to/class.php on line 123
```

Creating the `stdClass` like this solves that problem:

`$var = new \stdClass();`

Since I am still pretty new to namespaces, I am not exactly sure what the problem here is?

My guess is that in the first example, the `stdClass` would be created in the namespace of my class. This actually means the constructor of a class called `stdClass` existing in my namespace would be called, but since that class does not exist, an error is thrown.

In the second example, I signalize that I want to instantiate the class called `stdClass` from the global namespace, which somehow suddenly makes sense.

If anyone could elaborate what is happening here I would be very happy.

Comment: stdClass objects don't have any real use cases that arrays don't, why not just use an array?

Comment: namespaces let you override internal classes/functions. e.g. you can't normally do `function printf(...)` because printf is a core function. but that core function exists only in the top-level global namespace. `function foo\printf()` is entirely doable. stdClass only exists in the global namespace. it's not implicitly present in namespaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to understand the concept behind namespaces, and you are headed in the right direction on your analysis of what is happening.

When you are working inside of a namespace you are able to refer to names as *unqualified*, *qualified*, and *fully qualified*.

When you make a namespace you are telling PHP to organize (and resolve) the names of your classes, function, methods, etc. away from the same scope where the built-in PHP code lives along with any other code behind its own namespace.  It is away to organize your code and avoid naming collisions among libraries and built-in PHP functions.

Here is a brief on how names get resolved:

- If you are trying to resolve a name within the same namespace you can use the *unqualified name*.  So  for class `\Foo\Bar\Baz` you can use `new Baz();` as long as you are in namespace `\Foo\Bar`.
- If you are trying to resolve a name that is lower in the same parent namespace you can use the *qualified name*. So for class `\Foo\Bar\Baz` you would need to use `new Bar\Baz();` if you were in namespace `\Foo`.
- If you are trying to resolve a name that is not in your namespace or is in the global namespace (built-in PHP stuff) then you must use the *fully qualified name*.  If you are in namespace `\Foo\Bar` and you want to make use of something like the `mysqli` class you would need to call it by its fully qualified name. e.g. `new \mysqli()` Your question above is a perfect example that illustrates this.  Likewise, if you need to access a class in a totally different namespace you would also need the fully qualified name: `new \Third\Party\AppClass();`

So to summarize, you are right, the built-in `stdClass` does not exist in your namespace, therefore you need to access it by the fully qualified name.  The reason you must do thing this way had to do with conforming to the rules PHP uses when resolving names.

If you ever need to find out what namespace you are in it will be in the `__NAMESPACE__` constant.

In case you haven't already read it, here is the documentation on name resolution in PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rules.php

Answer (score 1):

The code is evaluated in your namespace and stdClass doesn't exist there. You are effectively answering your own question with your guess.

Answer (score 1):

Your guess is correct. Look at the comments in "class references" section of Example #1 on this page.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rules.php